# Javascript get data from sql using object with openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, web, openlayers-3

I added some points on the map using javascript(OpenLayers3). These points' positions are fetching from sql(randomly generated). I have to create a pop-up menu about each object on the map. This pop-up includes the data information of each selected point but ı dont know how to get the data from sql using the object on the map.

[Points Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSWsM.png)

[How to get data ? Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q80ca.png)

Comment: your pop-up has to be displayed when you click on the point, right ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to transfer ID from your sql for each object in map. You can add custom property in that way:

`var pointFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]),
    id: 25
});`

Next use `click` event to get feature and ID:

`map.on('click', function(evt) {
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
        function(feature) {
          return feature;
        });
    if (feature) {
        alert(feature.get('id'));
    }
});`

Here you go! All that remain is to make ajax request to your asp.net with ID as parameter.

Another way is to transfer ALL attributes from your sql on map from the beginning, so you won't need to make ajax request - you could just get properties from feature. But be careful as this solution will increase your point data greatly.